# Tools for documenting complex Flows

Tags: screen-flow, flow-screen-component

I was wondering if anyone may know a tool to get documentation of how a flow works.

The thing is, I have a quite complex screen flow, which was built some time ago and there's no written documentation about it.
The objective of such flow at the end is to create a record of a custom object called "Sales Sheet", based of values the user inputs and field values on multiple related records.

The problem is that it was built a long time ago, and the end users are seeing some unexpected results (probably because of changes in the business since it was first designed).
I'm currently working on documenting, for each field of the Sales Sheet a "formula" of how that field is calculated so they can review it and check if this is correct. However, as you may imagine, it's quite slow going through each loop, assignment, formula and screen elements to figure out the formula for each scenario (even more with flows of such size, where salesforce takes like 5 seconds to open the details screen of each element).

I was wondering if anyone knew of a tool that maybe could take the XML and throw a report or formula of how each value is calculated, or perhaps a better approach than the one I'm taking right now.

Thank you!

Comment: Vote for https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdh0EUAR/automatically-create-documentation-for-processes-builder-and-visual-flows

Answer (score 0):

I use LucidChart to create flow charts portraying the business logic to any Flow I create. I find it helpful to explain a process to non-technical users.

LucidChart does have an import XML tool that might be what you're looking for.